# Select multiple fields using createQueryBuilder() method in Sonata/Symfony2

Tags: symfony, sonata

I have a table that contains people's names in 3 fields: "lastname", "firstname", "middlename".
I need to get all 3 fields concatenated by the createQueryBuilder() method or somehow else.
My code looks like this:

```
$formMapper->add('collaborator', 'entity', array
            (
                'label' => 'acme.admin.person',
                'empty_value' => '',
                'class' => 'AcmeCoreBundle:Person',
                'query_builder' => function ($repository) {
                    return $repository
                        ->createQueryBuilder('p')
                        ->where('p.status = 1')
                        ->orderBy('p.lastname', 'ASC');
                },
                'property' => 'lastname'
            )
        );
```

Surely, now it only returns the "lastname".
How to modify it to get the result that i need?

Comment: you can mark answer as accepted see here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

One way is to define an unmapped property in your `Person` entity lets say `$titleConcat` now create a getter for the property and concat all 3 properties you want to show

```
protected $titleConcat;

public function getTitleConcat() {
    return $this->firstname.' '.$this->middlename. ' ' . $this->lastname;
}
```

Now in your `$formMapper` object define `'property' => 'titleConcat'`

```
$formMapper->add('collaborator', 'entity', array
            (
                'label' => 'acme.admin.person',
                'empty_value' => '',
                'class' => 'AcmeCoreBundle:Person',
                'query_builder' => function ($repository) {
                    return $repository
                        ->createQueryBuilder('p')
                        ->where('p.status = 1')
                        ->orderBy('p.lastname', 'ASC');
                },
                'property' => 'titleConcat'
            )
        );
```